# insert an array of data into database with API using laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and just started creation of apis to connect to the database. I'm able to send a single entry at a time to the database, now what i want to do is to pass an array of data to be inserted into the database but don't seem to find my way around

Controller

```
public function newSaveUser(Request $request) {
    $newFood = new Food;
    $newFood->name = $request->name;
    $newFood->save();
}
```

Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Food extends Model {
    //
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: You can use `create` method to save . For more check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Food extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


}
```

and then to insert data:

```
Food::create([
   'name' => $request->get('name')
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

firstly check the db connection is works or not.

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Food extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "write_table_name_here";
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

extend model in controller;

$newFood = new Food;

$newFood->name = $request->name;

$newFood->save();